# Flutter + Laravel Websocket + Pusher Replacement (Valet Secure)

Tags: laravel, flutter, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

I'm using [Beyondco Larevel Websockets](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction) on my Laravel Backend, and using [pusher_client](https://github.com/chinloyal/pusher_client) and [laravel_echo](https://pub.dev/packages/laravel_echo) on my Flutter frontend.

I've been trying to connect from my ios simulator into my Laravel Backend host, which is using valet secure, but failing.

My Flutter connections:

```
PusherClient getPusherClient(String token) {
  PusherOptions options = PusherOptions(
      host: 'my-local-server.test',
      wsPort: 6001,
      wssPort: 6001,
      cluster: DotEnv.env['PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'],
      encrypted: true,
      auth: PusherAuth('https://my-local-server.test/api/broadcasting/auth',
          headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'})
  );

  return PusherClient(DotEnv.env['PUSHER_APP_KEY'], options,
      enableLogging: true, autoConnect: false);
}
pusherClient = getPusherClient(token);
pusherClient.connect();
pusherClient.onConnectionStateChange((state) {
  print(
      "previousState: ${state.previousState}, currentState: ${state.currentState}");
});
pusherClient.onConnectionError((error) {
  print(error.message);
});
```

From https://my-local-server.test/laravel-websockets I never see the requests from Flutter, but if I fire an event from my Laravel backend, it gets logged.

Please help me with what's wrong in my setup, why I can't connect to my SSL valet server running laravel-websocket from my Flutter application.

Comment: did you get any error in console ?

Comment: @NidheeshMT No errors

Comment: https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/602 This thread might help. IOS SDK version 9 and higher have issues in connecting with laravel websocket